# Hide the "view exposed filter" form or reload the page after submit the form?

Tags: 6, ajax, views

I am using view exposed filter on a view display as "block". The block is added to dashboard.

I added a second function to "Apply" button using `hook_form_alter`. I want to hide the expose form of `view` after submit it. I added the jquery to hide the element using `drupal_add_js`. But it didn't work.

Is there any way to hide the form or reload the page after submit of expose form so i can hide the form on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function custom_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-YOURVIEWNAME') {
    if($_GET['xxx'] == 0){
      hide($form);
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't even remember my scenario. It was a very very old question. :P :)